# I try to compile this program and it comes up with an error, can anybody give assistance?

Tags: java, inheritance, error-handling

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot store to object array because "this.DogNames" is null
at GoldenRetriever.GR(IDemo.java:16)
at IDemo.main(IDemo.java:26)

```
class Dog {
    public String[] DogNames;
    String DogBreed;

    void PrintBreed(){System.out.println("Breed: " + DogBreed);}
    void PrintName(){System.out.println("Name(s): " + DogNames);}
    void PrintBoth(){
        System.out.println("Name(s): " + DogNames + "Breed: " + DogBreed);
    }
}

class GoldenRetriever extends Dog{
    public void GR(String... names){
        GoldenRetriever myGR = new GoldenRetriever();
        for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++){
            DogNames[i] = names[i];
        }
        myGR.DogNames = DogNames;
        myGR.DogBreed = "Golden Retriever";
    }
}

public class IDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        var myGoldenRetriever = new GoldenRetriever();
        myGoldenRetriever.GR("Buddy", "Dude");
        myGoldenRetriever.PrintName();
        myGoldenRetriever.PrintBreed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)   By the way, throwing a `NullPointerException` is a runtime, not a compilation, error.

Comment: You *succeeded* in compiling this program; you executed it; and it then *threw* this *exception.* Be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got NullPointerException because you did not instantiate the DogNames array

```
public String[] DogNames = new String[10] // where 10 is the size of your array;
```

and to display the content of the array do not just print DogNames because it won't display the content of the array it will display the classname + the hashcode you can read about it here [java-system-out-println-an-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270110/java-system-out-println-an-array)

```
    void PrintName(){System.out.println("Name(s): " + Arrays.toString(DogNames));}
    void PrintBoth(){System.out.println("Name(s): " + Arrays.toString(DogNames) + "Breed: " + DogBreed);}
```

and you can remove this part  GoldenRetriever myGR = new GoldenRetriever(); because you are creating a new object and assigning values to it so in main you won't have these values

```
    public void GR(String... names){
    for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++){
        DogNames[i] = names[i];
    }
    DogNames = DogNames;
    DogBreed = "Golden Retriever";
}
```

other things worth reading
[Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) /
[Java Constructor](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp)
to further improve your code